# php loop output data write in file

Tags: php, loops

Here is the code in `index1.php` file which has input array defined.

```
<form action="index2.php" method="post" name="form">

    Study: <input type="text" name="study[]">
    Bug: <input type="text" name="bug[]">
    Build File: <input type="text" name="bname[]" size="50">
    WAR File: <input type="text" name="wname[]" size="50">
```

`index2.php` following contain code. when i submit input values index2.php print them out with following info on web page. i want to save that same data in `text` file but i don't know how to write data in file in loop function.

```
<textarea name="data" cols="150" rows="20">

parallel (
<?php foreach($_POST['bname'] as $id => $value) { ?>
{
ignore(FAILURE) {
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;build( "Deploy2live",  BUILDFILE: "<?php echo $_POST["bname"][$id]; ?>", WARFILE: "<?php echo $_POST["wname"][$id]; ?>", STUDY: "<?php echo $_POST["study"][$id]; ?>", BUG: "<?php echo $_POST["bug"][$id]; ?>" )
}},
<?php } ?>
)

</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use file_put_contents("filename.txt",$data,FILE_APPEND)
https://www.php.net/file_put_contents

Comment: How that will fit in my example?

Comment: I am not sure of your exact circumstance but something like this might work:
http://paste.laravel.com/sau

Comment: You should post your code in here in case paste.laravel.com removed them.

Comment: log.txt putting everything in single line anyway we can use new lines for every line?